In こんな私でも自分を認められる, is 認められる potential or passive?
The below are lines made by Miku from Quintessential Quintuplets chapter 67. She is expressing her dissatisfaction with the status quo.

私たちは教師と生徒、それでいいと思ってた
私が一番の生徒になればいいと思ってた
こんな私でも自分を認められる
チャンスは誰にでも公平にあるんだって（思ってた？）

I am not sure whether to interpret 自分を認められる as "to be able to forgive myself" or "to get recognized." I initially thought thought the former is correct because if it is latter, it should be something like 自分を認めてもらう instead. However, it leaves me uncertainty with the meaning of チャンス in the following line. I think it means chance to get recognized. Maybe my initial interpretation of 自分を認められる is wrong?
I think this is probably not a question on Japanese language per se but reading comprehension but the reading comprehension tag exists, so I hope it is alright.

This is a simple potential expression. Reading this as an indirect passive sentence would imply Miku will be inconvenienced by "ending up with being acknowledged", but such an interpretation makes no sense here.
This (公平な)チャンス refers to an opportunity to deepen the relationship with the protagonist, not the possibility of being recognized. Note that, in Japanese, チャンス always refers to an opportunity for success, not just a mere possibility.
